# Changing layer order of vector tile layer

Tags: leaflet, vector-tiles, pbf, tippecanoe

I am creating a simple web map using vector tiles of type pbf.
The vector tiles are created with [tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) like:

```
tippecanoe -pC -P -z 19 -Z 15 -e builds --drop-densest-as-needed --extend-zooms-if-still-dropping piers.GeoJSON ... water.GeoJSON ... green.GeoJSON w --force
```

When I display the layers in leaflet using [vectorgrid](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid), I can see, that the water polygons are covering the piers.
The leaflet example code goes like this:

```
L.vectorGrid.protobuf('http://localhost:8080/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    maxNativeZoom: 16,
    vectorTileLayerStyles: {
    greenGeoJSON: {
        color: "#d4dad6",
        weight: 1,
        fillColor: "#ADD19E",
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        fill: true,
    },

    waterGeoJSON: function(properties, zoom) {
        var lineWidth = 0;
        if (properties.area > 10000000) {
            if (zoom == 15) {
                lineWidth = 3;
            }
            if (zoom == 16) {
                lineWidth = 3.25;
            }
            if (zoom == 17) {
                lineWidth = 3.5;
            }
            if (zoom >= 18) {
                lineWidth = 4;
            }
        }
        return ({
            weight: lineWidth,
            fillColor: "#99ccff",
            color: "#bfc7c8",
            opacity: 0.1,
            fill: true,
            fillOpacity: 1
            });
        },
        pierpolygonsGeoJSON: {
            weight: 1,
            fillColor: "#e3e3dc",
            color: "black",
            opacity: 1,
            fill: true,
            fillOpacity: 1
        }
    }
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Here is the current layer order:
[image: piers covered]

and this is the same map without the water layer:
[image: without water]

How can I reorder the layers, that are coming from a pbf? Can I change the pbf creation process so the water-layer will be at the right "zlevel"?

Comment: Changing layer order in PBF may not change something e.g when reading the PBF tile at https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/blob/master/src/Leaflet.VectorGrid.Protobuf.js#L141, it calls `new VectorTile` and this instance have a property `layers` that is an object (so with no order) https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mapbox/vector-tile#properties

Comment: Reading TODO section of plugin docs at https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid, one of the lines says: __- Sub-panes for the tile renderers (to set the "z-index" of layers/features)__. This indicates this is not yet possible also on the client side. Brute force solution would be to have three separate pbf layers, each displaying features for only one style, and putting those layers on separate map panes.

Answer (score 4):

The following comment on github made this thing work:
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/issues/167#issuecomment-451029240

Instead of using the CDN version of vectorgrid, download src and replace the `createTile` function with the content of the comment.

Add a `zorder` number to **all** of your `vectorTileLayerStyles`, otherwise you'll receive errors.

The above code would look like this then:

```
L.vectorGrid.protobuf('http://localhost:8080/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf', {
maxZoom: 19,
maxNativeZoom: 16,
vectorTileLayerStyles: {
greenGeoJSON: {
    color: "#d4dad6",
    weight: 1,
    fillColor: "#ADD19E",
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    fill: true,
    zorder:1
},

waterGeoJSON: function(properties, zoom) {
    var lineWidth = 0;
    if (properties.area > 10000000) {
        if (zoom == 15) {
            lineWidth = 3;
        }
        if (zoom == 16) {
            lineWidth = 3.25;
        }
        if (zoom == 17) {
            lineWidth = 3.5;
        }
        if (zoom >= 18) {
            lineWidth = 4;
        }
    }
    return ({
        weight: lineWidth,
        fillColor: "#99ccff",
        color: "#bfc7c8",
        opacity: 0.1,
        fill: true,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        zorder:2
        });
    },
    pierpolygonsGeoJSON: {
        weight: 1,
        fillColor: "#e3e3dc",
        color: "black",
        opacity: 1,
        fill: true,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        zorder:3
    }
}
}).addTo(mymap);
```

The higher `zorder` the later it will be drawn onto the canvas, and will cover underlying layers.

Answer (score 1):

It's dirty but you can force the layer order through the naming of the layers.
i.e. 0_waterGeoJSON and 1_greenGeoJSON

This is because the [layers are stored as a object](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-js#api-reference) which is an 'unordered' type. This means that when [Leaflet.VectorGrid iterates over the layers](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/blob/0079d72add0e1bd5dcd4fac3b85248cb854755da/src/Leaflet.VectorGrid.Protobuf.js#L151) to display them, they are consistently given in alphabetical order by the layer name. (at least for protobuf)